# Wrap a long line in a <blockquote> so that the lines are equal length

Tags: html, css

I have a `<blockquote>` element containing a long line (984 characters) with no spaces; only letters, digits, and symbols. Right now, it seems to be wrapping at symbols/punctuation, resulting in ugly-looking lines of random length. Is it possible to wrap the lines such that they are all (except the last) the same length?

I tried using `style="overflow-wrap:break-word;"` but to no avail.

Comment: `word-break: break-all` should work for you.

Comment: if word-break still didnt work, u could try, 'white-space:nowrap'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Word-Break: break-all`

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp

**Demo:** [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/et2a30xw/)

Answer (score 0):

We all seem to agree on `word-break: break-all`

Do note that some symbols like `?` will allow a random wrap too

```js
let possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

function makeText(num) {
  let text = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < num; i++)
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
  return text;
}
let text = makeText(984);
document.querySelector("blockquote.wrapped").textContent = text;
document.querySelector("blockquote.notWrapped").textContent = text;
possible += `+"*ç%&/()=?`;
document.querySelector("blockquote.notWRappedWithSymbols").textContent = makeText(984);
```

```css
blockquote.wrapped { word-break: break-all }
```

```html
<blockquote class="wrapped"></blockquote>
<blockquote class="notWrapped"></blockquote>
<blockquote class="notWRappedWithSymbols"></blockquote>
```